# How do you make the type of a param match the type of a param of a passed in Function Component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-types

Given the following typescript type for a generic React Component:

`type Props<T> = { renderedItem: FC<{ index: number; style: CSSProperties; data: T }>; itemData?: T; };`

And will be used as follows as I need the functional overload for this component:

`function Component<T extends any>(props: Props<T>): ReturnType<FC<Props<T>>>`

Is there anyway to make the type 'T' in itemData the same as 'T' in data in renderedItem even if 'T' can be anything including undefined.

I already tried the above generics but it is not helpful since it just gives me the type of `any`, it doesn't seem to narrow the type on `itemData`.

Comment: Using your code, and writing `Component({ renderedItem: (props: { /*…*/ data: number }) => <>{/*…*/}</>, itemData: 'foo' })` correctly gives me an error that “Type '`string`' is not assignable to type '`number`'.” So I am a little confused what the question is? Where are you getting `any`? So far as I can tell, the only way you should get that is if your `renderedItem` or `itemData` themselves are already `any` type.